# Gremlin 'table' method in Gremlin Scala or Java

Tags: database, scala, gremlin

How to I can the below query with Scala-Gremlin or even with Java-Gremlin:

```
gremlin> t = new Table()    
gremlin> g.v(1).out('knows').as('x').out('created').as('y').table(t)
==>v[5]
==>v[3]
gremlin> t
==>[x:v[4], y:v[5]]
==>[x:v[4], y:v[3]]
```

I can't find the method `table` :(

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the answer of Daniel Kuppitz seems to work for Java it is not working with the Scala wrapper.
So I did with the `select` method:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import com.tinkerpop.gremlin.scala._

graph.V.has("type", "VTM").as("vtm")
  .both("has").has("type", "VMP").as("vmp")
  .both("has").has("type", "AMP").as("amp")
  .both("has").has("type", "SUPPLIER").as("supplier")
  .select.cast(classOf[Row[Vertex]]).toList foreach { row =>
  println(row.getColumn("vtm"))
  println(row.getColumn("vmp"))
  println(row.getColumn("amp"))
  println(row.getColumn("supplier"))
}
```

Don't forget the imports for implicit convertions.
Tell me if I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty much the same in Java.

```
Table t = new Table();
Vertex v1 = graph.getVertex(1);
new GremlinPipeline<Vertex, Vertex>(v1).out("knows").as("x").out("created").as("y").table(t).iterate();
```

Cheers,
Daniel

Comment: Humm that means the GremlinScalaPipeline is different from the Java one. See my answer to know how I did in Scala.